# How do I setup regex to accept only [digit][white space][operator]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use a regulare expression that accepts only [Number] [1 only space but required] [operators as `+` `-` `/` `*`]

I tried this: `([0-9])\ +[-,+,/,*]`, but it didn't work for me as it also accpets characters coming after the operator, e.g. `5 + yyyy`. I just have to accept `5 +` which semantically corresponds to `[Number] [Operator]`.

Comment: Did you actually try something?

Comment: And? Did it work? If not, what did you get instead? You should show example input, expected output, and actual output. Show your actual code.

Comment: no it does not work, by this I accept everything for example "5 + yyyy"
I just have to accept 5[space]+, ....[Number] [space] [Operator]

Comment: And try it on one of these sites: https://regex101.com/, regexpal.com/, regexr.com/ etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this worked for me, I hope it helps:

```
([0-9]+ [+,\-,*,\/])/g
```

This way it will return every occurance that matches [number][whitespace][operator]. Tested here [Regex Tester](https://regex101.com/r/lB0dA0/1)